# How to get element from circular_buffer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-circularbuffer

I am using boost library in `MAC` (`xcode`). I have two questions about `boost::circular_buffer`.

1 - I am getting syntax error when declaring the circular_buffer

```
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(10);

Expected parameter decelerator
Expected ')'
```

2 - Second question is when I add element into `boost::circular_buffer` using push_back, how to extract / get the element from circular_buffer, `pop_front` does not give the element.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/example.html  `front()` and `pop_front()` or `back()` and `pop_back()`.

Comment: Yes, this example does not work, getting syntax error at (10) on line 
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(10);  Secondly I dont want to indexed the circular queue like cb[0], cb[1]. `pop_front`, `pop_back` does not give the element (may be I am wrong here, but example is not using these function to get the element)

Comment: Ditch the compiler that uses the word `decelerator` in an error message. It's only going to slow you down :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::circular_buffer<T>::front()` gives you a reference to the element at the "front", while `boost::circular_buffer<T>::pop_front()` will remove that element.

`boost::circular_buffer<T>::back()` gives you a reference to the element at the back, while `boost::circular_buffer<T>::pop_back()` removes that element.

It appears your syntax error is resulting from [the most vexing parse.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)  Try instead:

```
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb;
cb.set_capacity(10);
```

Or more succinctly:

```
boost::circular_buffer<int> cb((10));
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, set_capacity works fine but cb((10)) gives same error.